# Expected value for Markov Chain

Tags: probability, expectation, markov-chains, markov-process, hidden-markov-models

Let $(X_n)_{n\geq0}$ is a Markov chain with state space $I=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6 \}$ and transission matrix with transition probabilities $P_{i,i+1}=0.5, P_{i,0}=0.5$ and $P_{6,6}=1$ where $I\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$. If $T=inf\{m:X_m=6\}$

$$P=\begin{bmatrix} 0.5 & 0.5 & 0 &0 &0&0&0 \\  0.5 & 0 & 0.5 & 0&0&0&0\\ 0.5 & 0 & 0&0.5&0&0&0 \\0.5&0&0&0&0.5&0&0 \\0.5&0&0&0&0&0.5&0\\0.5&0&0&0&0&0&0.5\\0&0&0&0&0&0&1    \end{bmatrix}$$
How can I compute $E_3(T)$

Comment: What does the subscript $3$ mean in $E_3(T)$?

Comment: Also, what have you tried?  Do you know about (and have you tried using) conditional expectation?

Comment: Yes, the subscript means that the expected value starts in the state 3.

Comment: I have a idea: I used $E_3(T)=E(X_m=6)=\sum_{i=3}^{6}n(1/2)^{n-7}=112$ but I'm not sure of my answer.

Comment: I think that the key is to note that for $i = 0,\dots,5$, we have $E_i(T) = 1 + \frac 12(E_{i+1}(T) +  E_0(T))$

Comment: Using that we have $E_3(X_m=6)=1+1/2(\sum_{i=4}^{6}n(1/2)^{n-7}+\sum_{i=0}^{6}n(1/2)^{n-7})=1+1/2(64+240)=153$ ??? I'm not sure... :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you ask for can be computed by a standard result in Markov chain theory. In your case, you ask for the expected hitting time of $6$ given that you start at state $3$. Instead, compute $k_n:=E_n(T)$, i.e. the expected hitting time of $6$ starting from $n=0,1,...,6$. The theory then tells us, for instance in Markov Chains by J.R. Norris section 1.3, that $k_6=0$ and for $n\neq 6$, that
$$k_n=1+0.5(k_{n+1}+k_0).$$
Solving this recurrence relation will give you $k_n$ for each $n$ and then one can find $k_3$. Note, this is the exact relation that user Omnomnomnom suggested to investigate.

In general, if $(X_n)$ is a discrete time Markov chain on state space $S$ with probability transition matrix $P$, and $T_A:=\inf \{n : X_n\in A\}$, where $A\subset S$, then $k_i:=E_i(T_A)$ satisfies,
$$k_i=0, \,\text{ if } i\in A$$
and
$$k_i=1+\sum_{j\notin A} p_{ij} k_j, \, \text{ if } i\notin A.$$

By the way, the notation $E_3(T)=E_3(X_n=6)$ makes no sense. The expression "$X_n=6$" is not a random variable, (it is a value the RV may take), so you cannot take the expectation of it. For methods on solving the linear recurrence relations that result from the expected hitting time equation, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients) , or ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for. :D